# Trying to create custom error pages with nginx

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I'm working with nginx 1.4.7 - Windows and Tomcat server. In local development

I'm trying to create custom error pages when tomcat is offline, handling errors from nginx, but I think I have something wrong, because nginx is showing its own error page.

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name  127.0.0.1;
        root C:\Users\joseantonio\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps;


        error_page 500 501 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root errors;
            internal;
            allow all;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
            proxy_connect_timeout 1;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you expect `root errors;` to point to? As I understand it, it will be relative to the `nginx` configuration directory.

Comment: You're right, that was my problem. I was routing from webapps, the tomcat directory, but chaning "root errors;" to "root html;", folder inside nginx directory, it works!